# Could not ping ESP8266 Wifi module connected to an Arduino

Tags: networking, wifi, esp8266, communication, arduino

I have been working with a water flow counter which sends data over wifi. I'm using an ESP8266 wifi module. Everything is correctly connected and I've gotten to the point where it's correctly connected to the wifi network and everything, except when I try to ping its IP adress from the cmd (192.168.1.125) it times out.

I know this info has something to do: I have read it's something about my ipv4 not being in the 192.168... range. But i'm not sure if that's the issue or if so, how to fix it.

I should state that the network is my company's and not my home wi-fi so I would not be able to change the network's IP adress (Maybe if it's really necessary I could speak to the network manager). Would the solution be to match the ESP8266's IP adress to the range of that of the network?) (192.192...)

ESP2866 Module IP adress: 192.168.1.125
My IPV4 Adress is: 192.192.10.125
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS servers: 192.192.10.129
Default gateway: 192.192.10.252

Comment: The ESP8266 is in one subnet and your PC in another is the routing between these networks functional?

Comment: They have the same subnet mask: 255.255.255.0. I recently changed the module's IP adress to the same of the computer. I don't know how this is not creating any conflict. Now if y try to ping from the cmd it does respond, but Idon't know if it's the computer or the module the one responding as they now have the same IP adress: 192.192.10.129

Comment: https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/2409/14

Comment: So, should I forward a port on my router as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

255.255.255.0 is the value that determines the **SIZE** of the subnet.

192.168.1.xxx  with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 is a subnet spanning from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255.

192.168.10.xxx with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 is a subnet spanning from 192.168.10.0 to 192.168.10.255.

A router is needed for transporting IP from one subnet to another. Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)

All devices in the subnet MUST have a unique IP & MAC address!

Cisco has a good "IP Addressing and Subnetting for New Users"

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html